# mongodb db.repairDatabase leaves only 101 documents out of ~30 millions

Tags: mongodb

On my local machine I had a database with about 30 millions documents in a collection. When I entered a command in mongoshell:
`db.repairDatabase();` - it left only 101 documents in a collection. Why it behaves in a such way? Where are my another ~30 millions documents now?

**EDIT:**

I've updated all mongo instances to latest version 2.4.5. Problem disappeared.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that with "mln" you mean "mil" as in "million"?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: I hope you have a backup !?

Comment: Fortunately it was my local version of the DB. Of course I didn't experiment on the working copy.

Comment: I've updated all mongo instances to latest version 2.4.5. Problem disappeared.

Comment: What version of MongoDB were you using when you had the original problem (i.e. before upgrading to 2.4.5)?  Also, what command were you using the count the documents?  The count of 101 happens to be the [default batch size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/) for query cursors which seems suspiciously coincidental.

Comment: I used 2.0.6 version. For counting I used db.collection.count() command